# DIV CSS Layout - fixed position expand parent

Tags: html, css, position

I'm looking at a 'drag and drop' script which works for my needs, but I have a couple of problems with the DIV positioning and getting a DIV to be fixed but allow to expand it's parent.

I've created a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/Tom_T/full/kXjLAw/) example.

Basically I have a `list` on the `left` of the page which may grow or shrink. That div expands and contracts correctly.

One the right of the page I have a `dropzone` the users can drag from the list and fill up the drop zone.

If the list is longer than the page,  when the user scrolls down I wan to have the right pane (outlined in YELLOW) to scroll down the page with it. When the user scrolls up I want the YELLOW pane to scroll back up and eventually arrive back at it's original location.

As items are dragged from the left to the right the YELLOW pane expands. But it expands over the DRAG DIV, it should make the drag div expand so the YELLOW pane stays with in it.

Please some one advise how I get this to work. 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add padding to this

```
#right_container {
padding: 20px;
}
```

delete position

```
#right {
position :absolute;
}
```

what am I misinterpreting this..

Comment: Thanks that allows it to expand the Drag DIV. How about having the YELLOW pane move up & down as the user scrolls ?